# when() not working in RestAssured using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, rest-assured, junit5

I am trying to run the following code with eclipse but it will give me the error: "The method when() is undefined for the type LastLabTest". I have imported the libraries but still it gives me that error. I am using eclipse with junit5.

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.RestAssured.*; 
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.filter.log.RequestLoggingFilter;
import io.restassured.filter.log.ResponseLoggingFilter;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

import org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class LastLabTest {

private RequestSpecification specification;
@BeforeClass
public void inItSpec() {
    specification = new RequestSpecBuilder()
            .setContentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .setBaseUri("http://openlibrary.org/")
            .addFilter(new RequestLoggingFilter())
            .addFilter(new ResponseLoggingFilter())
            .build();
}

@Test
public void getByName() {

                when().get("https://swapi.co/api/people/1")
                .then().log().all()
                .statusCode(200)
                .and()
                .body("name", equals("Luke Skywalker"));
}
}
```

Comment: You'll also need to replace `@BeforeClass` (from JUnit 4) with `@BeforeEach` (from JUnit Jupiter, a.k.a. JUnit 5).

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `static` is missing in the line

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
```

=>

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
```

Comment: it gives me another error: "The static import io.restassured.RestAssured must be a field or member type"

Comment: Not the first import, the import that ends with `.*;`.

Answer (score 0):

keyword static is missing in  import io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
correct : import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).